# mysql datediff:get data between days

Tags: php, mysql

I am building mysql query dynamically. It is working fine. Problem is in that query i want to add datediff function or between. So, when user select show data older than 10,15,30 days. it will show data accordingly.

Here is the code which i am using at the moment.

```
<?php
require_once 'include/db.php';    
$firstname = 'Alpha';
$lastname = 'Romeo';
$older_than = 30;

$query = "SELECT fname,lname,uid,join_date FROM users";

$cond = array();
$params = array();

if (!empty($firstname)) {
    $cond[] = "fname = ?";
    $params[] = $firstname;
}

if (!empty($lastname)) {
    $cond[] = "lname = ?";
    $params[] = $lastname;
}

if (!empty($older_than)) {
    $cond[] = "join_date = ?";
    $params[] = $older_than;
}



if (count($cond)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
}
echo $query;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);


 $bind = array(); 
foreach($params as $key => $val){ 
    $bind[$key] = &$params[$key];
} 
$types = str_repeat("s", count($params));

array_unshift($bind, $types); 

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bind);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($fname, $lname, $uid,$older_than);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $fname, $lname, $uid,$older_than;
    }


?>
```

As per my understanding I need to change the code over here.

```
if (!empty($older_than)) {
    $cond[] = "join_date = ?";
    $params[] = $older_than;
}
```

Please advise me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATE_SUB` and `<`.

```
if (!empty($older_than)) {
    $cond[] = "join_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY)";
    $params[] = $older_than;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try.